# Eclipse CDT C++20 Support

Tags: eclipse-cdt, c++20

is there a way to enable support of C++20 features in Eclipse 2020-03 (CDT 9.11)? I mean to get rid of incorrect syntax highlighting like igroring newly added keywords like 'concept', 'requires' and others as defined in C++20 standard? I have a GCC10 supporting those stuff installed and in usage, so the code is built without any troubles but Eclipse CDT still complains about it... 
Thanks to anyone willing to advise. Martin

Answer (score 2):

There's no support for C++20 in Eclipse CDT. Actually the support to C++17 is quite high but not totally completed yet. If you need C++20 support is better to use another IDE at the moment or implement the support in CDT if you want.

Comment: I am browsing the web trying to find some other IDE having the support for C++20 but I am not successful. Could you share a hint which C++20 capable IDE to try?

Comment: @MartinKopecký I use Ecplise CDT for C++20, since its 'support' is only visual and i can disable the IDE errors and warnings, it doesn't really matter. Only some color hightlights are missing, e.g. for `consteval`. But as long as the compiler works, everything builds as it should when configured correctly in the project settings. All the compiler output also results in correct markers from Eclipse. (I use GCC 10.2.0 from winlibs.com as a compiler, on Windows.)

Comment: @xamid could you please advise me how to disable those annoying IDE errors and warnings coming out from this lack of c++20 support in Eclipse 2020-03? I have not been successful yet finding appropriate settings... thank you

Comment: @MartinKopecký Yes. To disable custom errors and warnings, go to Window, Preferences, C/C++, Code Analysis and disable what u want, and then make sure at Project, Properties, C/C++ General, Code Analysis to have 'Use workspace settings' enabled, or instead disable the warnings and errors there. The syntax error (occurs for unknown keywords such as `consteval`) can be disabled under Windows, Preferences, General, Editors, Text Editors, Annotations, C/C++ Occurrences. I disabled only 'Vertical ruler' to still have marked new keywords, but disabling them all will leave no sign of them.

Comment: @MartinKopecký Also using the search function in Eclipse within Properties or Preferences tends to be helpful, as well as using Google. I just googled what you asked me and it took me a few seconds to get the answer.

Comment: @MartinKopecký Oops, the "C/C++ Occurrences" was meant to be "C/C++ Indexer Markers", and I disabled only the "Text as [...]" there. (My Google search for "eclipse c++ disable syntax error" gave that result wrong.)

Comment: This answer seems somewhat dated, Eclipse CDT now supports the 2a standard but not the 2b standard. Unfortunately for me ranges and views seems to be in 2b. I'm looking for how to make Eclipse CDT use gcc12 which does support 2b (fully supports c++2)

Comment: @greywolf82  There is support for c++ v20 now in Eclipse, you just have to enable the extra flag in the compiler.  --std=c++20.  Tested it and it works for both Eclipse and VS code.

Comment: @MartinKopecký  Eclipse does support c++ v20 now.  Or at least the COMPILER supports it.  I don't know if Eclipse will properly pickup the syntax.  I assume it will since it is using MYSYS64 but I am not positive.  However the test code seems to indicate that it IS running v20.

Comment: @ScottMilella Eclipse doesn't support C++20, and will never do. Neither it will fully support C++17. Eclipse doesn't have a compiler. `--std=c++20` has nothing to do with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way now as I just enabled it and confirmed it.

To enable C++ v20 in Eclipse on a per project basis (I haven't yet been able to figure out how to make it a default for ALL projects) you will want to do the following in Eclipse:

To enable C++ v20 for a specific project you right click on your project and go to Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous
and in the box for Other Flags add "--std=c++20" to the end of it.

You can verify it with this code:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

     if (__cplusplus == 202002L)
                 std::cout << "Your running C++20" << endl;
              else if    (__cplusplus == 201703L)
                  std::cout << "Your running C++17" << endl;
              else if (__cplusplus == 201402L)
                  std::cout << "Your running C++14" << endl;
              else if (__cplusplus == 201103L)
                  std::cout << "Your running C++11" << endl;
              else if (__cplusplus == 199711L)
                  std::cout << "Your running C++98" << endl;
              else
                  std::cout << "pre-standard C++" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To enable the same thing on Visual Studio Code this URL was able to help me get it done:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mw7Jfzavx0U

If someone out there knows how to make this a default for ALL C/C++ projects I would love to know how. (still looking, will come back and update if I find the answer to this).

Here is a pic of my Eclipse terminal window showing the C++ v20 is active:
[image]